# how can you ask for n input from a user and then ask for more inputs based on those n inputs in python?

Tags: python

For example: how many products do you sell? input = 2, cookies milk

cookies:
input: how much they cost:
input: sales price:

milk:
input: how much they cost:
input: sales price:

prod_num - (str(input("how many products do you sell: ")))
products = list(map(str, input("Please list the products you sell (Ex: Bread Cookies Milk) ").split()))

Comment: Ask how many products, convert that input to an integer.  Then loop that many times to ask for each product.

Comment: @JohnGordon I thought of that, but then how do you make for example: the sales price of each product not overwrite each other in the loop?

Comment: `not overwrite each other in the loop` - store them in a dictionary.

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 2):

So one thing you could do is, after you ask what are the products the person sells, you iterate through each one of them, and ask the person for the price of the product, like so:

```
productsCount = input("How many products do you sell?");

products = input("Please list the products you sell, separated by a comma: ").split(",");

prices = [];

for i in range(len(products)):
    prices.append(input("How much does the " + products[i] + " cost?"));

print(prices);
```

This way you get a list with the products the person sells, and another list with the price of each of the products, in correct order.

I'm goign to be honest, I didn't quite understand what you wanted, I think that's it. If you need anything else or if my answer was not what you wanted, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Ask for a numeric input from a user:

`product_amount = int(input("How many products?: "))`

Then, store user responses. The way I would do it is in a nested list:

```
product_info = []

for x in range(product_amount):
    current_product = []
    current_product.append(input("Product name: "))
    # repeat for as many questions as necessary
    product_info.append(current_product)
```